# how to properly refresh p:dataView component after EntityManager saves data

Tags: jpa, jsf, primefaces, eclipselink

So, I've encountered this situation several times when I have a component that displays records, for instance, a list of shipping addresses in a p:dataView component (but it could be any other similar component).

Each row displays a shipping address and within each row, I have an edit and delete command buttons, as shown in next snippet:

```
<p:dataView id="dvBillingAddresses"
    ...
    <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil" 
        oncomplete="PF('editBillingAddressDlg').show()"
        ...
```

The edit command button would show following dialog:

```
<p:dialog header="Billing Address Details" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
    widgetVar="editBillingAddressDlg" responsive="true" width="450">
    ...
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="pi pi-check" actionListener="#{bean.saveBillingAddress}"
        ...
```

So record would be saved by calling bean method and at the end of said method, I would call PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("...dvBillingAddresses") to refresh the p:dataView component.

However, what always happens is that the component is refreshed before the data has been completely commited to datasource, causing component to refresh with old data.

What I usually end up doing is to use an ajax close event on the edit dialog to allow extra time to update data.

```
<p:dialog header="Billing Address Details" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
    widgetVar="editBillingAddressDlg" responsive="true" width="450">
    <p:ajax event="close" update="...dvBillingAddresses" immediate="true" global="false" />
    ...
```

When I have to update components after a confirmation, and since p:confirmDialog doesn't support ajax close events; I catch the click event on the confirmation button and programmatically click a dummy command button that in turn updates the component.

I know these can't be the right approach, as they feel a bit hackish, but so far this has allowed me to continue development.

Ideally, the component should wait to refresh until the entity's @PostLoad event is fired, even if a spinning refresh icon has to show.

I'm using PrimeFaces v11, eclipselink, mysql, jakartaee v8.0 on payara server.

How is everybody else handling this?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `update=` attribute to your `<p:commandButton/>`, so the dataView will be updated after the `bean.saveBillingAddress()` action is performed.

```
<p:dialog header="Billing Address Details" showEffect="fade" modal="true"
widgetVar="editBillingAddressDlg" responsive="true" width="450">
<h:form id="editBillingAddressForm">
....
<f:facet name="footer">
    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="pi pi-check"
     action="#{bean.saveBillingAddress}"
     update="@form ...dvBillingAddresses"
     oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('editBillingAddressDlg').hide()"/>
```

Comment: Hi stefan, that was the first approach I used, but it didn't work. Using PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("...dvBillingAddresses")  or directly setting this in the update attribute in the commandButtin would be equivalent. The issue is that the component refreshed before the dataset was updated. As a test, clicking another button with the update attribute set to update the dataView, would correctly refresh data.